# JSON nested serialisation

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Assume there is a data type

```
data V = V { a :: Int, x :: Int, y :: Int }
```

It has a correspondent JSON view

E.g. `V { a = 1, x = 2, y = 3 }` need to be serialised like

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "nested": {
    "x": 2,
    "y": 3
  }
}
```

What `ToJSON` instance would look like in that case?

---

What I've tried:

```
instance ToJSON V where
  toEncoding (V a b c) = 
    pairs (  "a" .= a
          <> ("nested" .= pairs ("x" .= x <> "y" .= y))
          )


<interactive>:6:10: error:
    • No instance for (GHC.Generics.Generic V)
        arising from a use of ‘aeson-1.1.1.0:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.$dmtoJSON’
    • In the expression:
        aeson-1.1.1.0:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.$dmtoJSON @V
      In an equation for ‘toJSON’:
          toJSON = aeson-1.1.1.0:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.$dmtoJSON @V
      In the instance declaration for ‘ToJSON V’

<interactive>:6:68: error:
    • No instance for (ToJSON Encoding) arising from a use of ‘.=’
    • In the second argument of ‘(<>)’, namely
        ‘("nested" .= pairs ("x" .= x <> "y" .= y))’
      In the first argument of ‘pairs’, namely
        ‘("a" .= a <> ("nested" .= pairs ("x" .= x <> "y" .= y)))’
      In the expression:
        pairs ("a" .= a <> ("nested" .= pairs ("x" .= x <> "y" .= y)))

<interactive>:6:87: error:
    • No instance for (ToJSON (V -> Int)) arising from a use of ‘.=’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the first argument of ‘(<>)’, namely ‘"x" .= x’
      In the first argument of ‘pairs’, namely ‘("x" .= x <> "y" .= y)’
      In the second argument of ‘(.=)’, namely
        ‘pairs ("x" .= x <> "y" .= y)’
(0.01 secs,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how instance may look like:

```
data V = V { a :: Int, x :: Int, y :: Int }

instance ToJSON V where
    toJSON (V a x y) = object
        [ "a" .= a
        , "nested" .= object
            [ "x" .= x
            , "y" .= y ]
        ]
```

You can test it in `ghci`:

```
ghci> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
ghci> B.putStrLn $ encode (V 1 2 3)
{"nested":{"x":2,"y":3},"a":1}
```

**UPD** (regarding `toEncoding`):

You most likely don't want to define `toEncoding`. This method has default implementation and it's defined using `toJSON` method. But `toJSON` method has no implementation for general case. It has only `default` implementation for `Generic` data types.

Your implementation if almost fine except it has typo: `"x" .= x <> "y" .= y` in method body and `(V a b c)` in pattern matching (thus it uses `x` variable as function and you got those creepy errors). And you need to derive `Generic` for your `V` data type for this to work. And you need to use [`pair`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.1.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Encoding-Internal.html#v:pair) function from internals instead of `.=` in one place. Here is full version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Data.Aeson (ToJSON (..), pairs, (.=))
import Data.Aeson.Encoding.Internal (pair)

data V = V { a :: Int, x :: Int, y :: Int } deriving (Generic)

instance ToJSON V where
    toEncoding (V a x y) = 
        pairs ("a" .= a <> (pair "nested" $ pairs ("x" .= x <> "y" .= y)))
```

But be aware of possible inconsistency:

```
ghci> encode (V 1 2 3)
"{\"a\":1,\"nested\":{\"x\":2,\"y\":3}}"
ghci> toEncoding (V 1 2 3)
"{\"a\":1,\"nested\":{\"x\":2,\"y\":3}}"
ghci> toJSON (V 1 2 3)
Object (fromList [("a",Number 1.0),("x",Number 2.0),("y",Number 3.0)])
```

Comment: nice, what about `toEncoding`?